# Help for Garch-Process

Tags: time-series

I have questions about the Garch-Process.

For example I simulate a Garch-Process:

```
list=RandomFunction[GARCHProcess[2, {.1}, {.2}], {0, 500}]
```

And I estimate my Parameters:

```
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[list, {"GARCH", {1, 1}}];
```

I can also get my Parameters with

```
estimatedProc2 = 
EstimatedProcess[list, GARCHProcess[1, 1], 
ProcessEstimator -> "MaximumConditionalLikelihood"]
```

1. What's the difference between TimeSeriesModelFit[] and  ProcessEstimator -> "MaximumConditionalLikelihood"?
2. How I can get the value of the Loglikelhood-function for my estimated parameters?

Comment: You have asked 6(!!) questions here and you still don't format your posts/code properly -- go to the help centre, read how to do that and format your post accordingly.

Comment: Also,  you never voted! See below for some advice

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: In general `TimeSeriesModelFit`, because it attempts to find fits to multiple models, uses faster and less accurate estimation methods. Using `EstimatedProcess` allows you to specifically set which method to use and even use suboptions.  It also seems that `LogLikelihood` for `GARCHProcess` is not yet implemented.

Comment: Ok, thanks...
but: which models use     TimeSeriesModelFit? I would say     LogLikelihood.
It's a pity, that    Loglikelihood isnt implemented yet...

Comment: @StefanR The reason for `LogLikelihood` not being implemented for `GARCHProcess` might be that `SliceDistribution` is also not defined for `GARCHProcess`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, I spoke to the developers, and slices of ARCH/GARCH are not known. One way to proceed would be to allow computation of conditional likelihood (conditioned on initial values). We may or may not add that in the future.